# Libvirt with bridged Interface: DHCP for Guests from Host

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

I am setting up a new host wih libvirt and qemu/kvm. I would love to manage the IPs on the host instead inside of the guests, so it would be great to define IPs via DHCP for the guests via virsh.

The bridge is setup with networkd, I configured the br0 for virsh with the following xml:

```xml
 <name>br0</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0"/>
  <dhcp>
    <range start="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" end="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" />
    <host mac="52:54:00:xx:xx:xx" name="hostname" ip="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" />
  </dhcp>
</network>
```

But the VMs are not able to get the IPs from the host dhcp server. Instead, they are trying to get an IP from the dhcp server from my provider. It works fine when I define a static ip on the guest.

Is there a way to serve dhcp for a bridget interface on the host?

Comment: The [doc](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#virtual-network) says that DHCP is supposed to be provided outside of libvirt. It is unclear whether that means that DHCP *cannot* be provided by libvirt, but you could check for a `dnsmasq` process on the host. If there isn't any, you could launch one yourself. In any case, the provider DHCP server is still there and will respond, too, except if you tell it to ignore the guest's MAC. If that is not possible, perhaps a netfilter rule on the bridge can block traffic to/from the provider's DHCP server.

Comment: It looks like you configured your whole host to be a bridge with a physical interface set as a port. Usually you create a bridge but use it as an interface to *route* rather than *bridge*. To be sure about this: `ip link show type bridge; ip link show type bridge_slave`. *Or* you're using macvtap for the guests. (again then: `ip link show type macvtap` when at least a guest is running).

Comment: In case this was intentional, you should edit your question and state your goal. Replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with correct IP addresses from [rfc5737](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5737) (for public) or rfc1918 (for private) to help readers understand. And then tell if the guests should have as router the host or the ISP's router.